# How do you capture sound from the sound card in Java?

Tags: java, audio, capture

I'm making a program that lets you access a computer remotely and control it. So far, everything from key strokes, mouse clicks, mouse pointer, and remote display works perfectly. My next step was to send audio from the remote computer to the controlling computer. I've searched and search, but I've only found information on recording microphone input. I need to know how to capture the sound from the computer's sound card and send that via Socket. An example of the microphone capture code looks like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Line;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.Port;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;

    public class Start {

    public static TargetDataLine line;

        public static void main(String[] args){
        AudioFormat format = getAudioFormat();
        Line.Info info = Port.Info.SPEAKER;
        try {
            line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            line.open(format);
            line.start();

            Thread stop = new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                line.stop();
                line.close();
            }
        };
        stop.start();

        AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(line);

        File file = new File("C:/Users/Savannah/Desktop/sound.au");
        file.createNewFile();

        AudioSystem.write(ais, AudioFileFormat.Type.AU, file);
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public static AudioFormat getAudioFormat(){
        float sampleRate = 16000;
        int sampleSizeInBits = 8;
        int channels = 2;
        boolean signed = true;
        boolean bigEndian = true;
        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits,
                                             channels, signed, bigEndian);
        return format;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To capture the sound from the computer's sound card and send that via Socket you  can use below code. First run server then run client class.

```
public class Server {
ServerSocket MyService;
Socket clientSocket = null;
InputStream input;
AudioFormat audioFormat;
SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;
byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];
static Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

Server() throws LineUnavailableException {

    try {
        Mixer mixer_ = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[0]);
        audioFormat = getAudioFormat();
        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
        sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
        sourceDataLine.open(audioFormat);
        sourceDataLine.start();
        MyService = new ServerSocket(500);
        clientSocket = MyService.accept();

        input = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        while (input.read(tempBuffer) != -1) {
            sourceDataLine.write(tempBuffer, 0, 10000);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
    float sampleRate = 8000.0F;
    int sampleSizeInBits = 8;
    int channels = 1;
    boolean signed = true;
    boolean bigEndian = false;
    return new AudioFormat(
            sampleRate,
            sampleSizeInBits,
            channels,
            signed,
            bigEndian);
}

public static void main(String s[]) throws LineUnavailableException {
    Server s2 = new Server();
}}
```

And client side:

```
public class Client {
boolean stopCapture = false;
AudioFormat audioFormat;
TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
BufferedOutputStream out = null;
BufferedInputStream in = null;
Socket sock = null;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Client tx = new Client();
    tx.captureAudio();
}
private void captureAudio() {
    try {
        sock = new Socket("192.168.1.5", 500);
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        in = new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
        Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
        audioFormat = getAudioFormat();
        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(
                TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat);
        Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[2]);

        targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(dataLineInfo);
        targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
        targetDataLine.start();

        Thread captureThread = new CaptureThread();
        captureThread.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
class CaptureThread extends Thread {

    byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];

    @Override
    public void run() {
        stopCapture = false;
        try {
            while (!stopCapture) {
                int cnt = targetDataLine.read(tempBuffer, 0,
                        tempBuffer.length);
                out.write(tempBuffer);
           }
           } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}

private AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
    float sampleRate = 8000.0F;

    int sampleSizeInBits = 8;

    int channels = 1;

    boolean signed = true;

    boolean bigEndian = false;

    return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed,
            bigEndian);
}}
```